# How to build Active Record with multiple associations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I defined these 3 models in Rails3.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :questions
  has_many :answers

class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :answers

class Answer < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :question
```

I wrote RSpec like this:

```
describe "user associations" do
  before :each do
    @answer = @user.answers.build question: @question
  end

  it "should have the right associated user" do
    @answer.user.should_not be_nil
  end

  it "should have the right associated question" do
    @question.should_not be_nil
    @answer.question.should_not be_nil #FAIL!!
  end
```

But I always get the following error:

```
Failures:

  1) Answer user associations should have the right associated question
     Failure/Error: @answer.question.should_not be_nil
       expected: not nil
            got: nil
```

I guess this line is wrong:

```
@answer = @user.answers.build question: @question
```

But how should I build answer object?

**Update:** Thanks everyone, I found I should have to write like this:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe Answer do
  before :each do
    @user = Factory :user 
    asker = Factory :user, :user_name => 'someone'
    @question = Factory :question, :user => asker
  end

  describe "user associations" do
    before :each do
      @answer = Factory :answer, :user => @user, :question => @question
    end

    it "should have the right associated user" do
      @answer.user.should_not be_nil
    end

    it "should have the right associated question" do
      @answer.question.should_not be_nil
    end
  end
end
```

Here is spec/factories.rb:

```
Factory.define :user do |user|
  user.user_name "junichiito"
end

Factory.define :question do |question|
  question.title "my question"
  question.content "How old are you?"
  question.association :user
end

Factory.define :answer do |answer|
  answer.content "I am thirteen."
  answer.association :user
  answer.association :question
end
```

Comment: on the face of it this looks right. have you tried adding a `debugger`?

Comment: Where do you create the `@question` instance, could you show that code?

Comment: I have never used debugger and don't know how to use it. Do you know any resources to learn?

Comment: Take a look at the Rails Guide "Debugging Rails Applications" http://guides.rubyonrails.org/debugging_rails_applications.html

Comment: I think the error occurs because you are building on associations of unsaved instances. In this case, I suspect that `@user` has not been saved, and therefore has no ID.

Comment: @rdvdijk Maybe so. Both user and question are built from Factory girl.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once I explicitly save the `@user` instance, the spec doesn't fail anymore. Here's my version:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe Answer do
  before :each do
    @user = User.new
    @user.save!
    @question = @user.questions.build 
    @question.save!

    @answer = @user.answers.build question: @question
    @question.answers << @answer
  end

  it "should have the right associated user" do
    @answer.user.should_not be_nil
  end

  it "should have the right associated question" do
    @question.should_not be_nil
    @answer.question.should_not be_nil # SUCCESS!
  end
end
```